# Multiple line file into one string

Tags: python, file-io

Hello I'm making a python program that takes in a file. I want this to be set to a single string. My current code is:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    title = f.readline().strip();
    content = f.readlines();
```

The text file (simplified) is:

```
Title of Document
asdfad
adfadadf
adfadaf
adfadfad
```

I want to strip the title (which my program does) and then make the rest one string. Right now the output is:

```
['asdfad\n', 'adfadadf\n', ect...]
```

and I want:

```
asdfadadfadadf ect...
```

I am new to python and I have spent some time trying to figure this out but I can't find a solution that works. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So far, most people appear to be assuming that you want you strip out all leading and trailing spaces, and EOL characters. Do you want these removed, preserved, or do you want EOL characters converted to spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
with open('/tmp/test.txt') as f:
    title=f.next()       # strip title line
    data=''.join(line.rstrip() for line in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.pop(0)` to remove the first line from content.

Then [str.join(iterable)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). You'll also need to strip off the newlines.

```
content.pop(0)
done = "".join([l.strip() for l in content])
print done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to read the entire file, then remove the newlines instead of joining together:

```
with open('somefile') as fin:
    next(fin, None) # ignore first line
    one_big_string = fin.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the rest of the file in a single chunk, just call the `read()` function:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    title = f.readline().strip()
    content = f.read()
```

This will read the file until EOF is encountered.